# Removing time from Jquery timepicker plugin and add New

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I am using Jquery timePicker plugin.
On Page Load i am appending time from 7:00am to 10 Pm

```
$(".timePickerDropDown").timePicker({
    startTime: "07:00",  // Using string. Can take string or Date object.
    endTime: new Date(0, 0, 0, 22, 00, 0),  // Using Date object.
    show24Hours: false,
    separator: ':',
    step: 15
});
```

But after that i have to load Custom time by passing to the function:
.

```
function AppointmentTime(startTime) {
    debugger;
    if ($('.timePickerDropDown').length > 0) {

            $(".time-picker-12hours").html('');
            $(this).timePicker({
                startTime: startTime,  // Using string. Can take string or Date object.
                endTime: new Date(0, 0, 0, 22, 00, 0),  // Using Date object.
                show24Hours: false,
                separator: ':',
                step: 15
            });
    }

}
```

.

Now i pass 10:00 am to this then it should have to display time from !0:00 am to 10:00 PM. But it still displays time from 7:00 AM to 10:00 PM
.

Comment: Could you link to the library you're using please

Comment: jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

Comment: jquery.timePicker.min.js

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$(this).timePicker({`  use `$(".timePickerDropDown").timePicker({` in that function.

`$(this)` in function does not correspond to any element.

Answer (score 0):

here you can get Timepicker library from here. It's free and good documantation.

[Here](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/)